# TS Stream Transport Over UDP from .TS files

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to transport ts stream (.ts files) over UDP.

I have used the below pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc =location=a.ts ! tsparse ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host="IP" port="port"
```

But, i am getting end of the stream within fraction of seconds.

At, Receiver end i am receiving some data only.

Warning arises when i set do-timestamp=true for filesrc.

```
0:00:00.051245178  4751       0xe494a0 WARN        mpegtspacketizer mpegtspacketizer.c:1388:calculate_skew: delta - skew: 5124091:34:25.044918089 too big, reset skew
```

TS file is created by decode and mpegtsmux of a yuv file.

That TS file is properly working when i directly demux & decode it.

But when i stream that ts file through UDP, then this problem arises.

**How can i transport ts stream over UDP?**

Answer (score 0):

MPEG2-TS carry timestamps, for decoding and presentation DTS/PTS. You obviously need to insert restamping the timestamps into your pipeline.

When you decode it, your local decoder might only use the relative time information from your timestamps, or discard them completely and recalculate timing from the bitrate, which works fine in most, nearly all streams (VLC didn't obey timestamps for years, and only learned it in recent releases).

maybe somebody can edit this answer, and give the right keyword to insert in the pipeline.